# Counting number of unique IDs per group at certain time points

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to find the number of participants per gene at different time points. I'm attempting to do this with a nested for loop, however, I can't seem to figure it out. Here's something I've been trying:

```
IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique<- select(IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique, cdr3aa, gene, ID, Timepoint)
participant_list <- unique(IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique$gene)
time_list<- unique(IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique$Timepoint)
for (c in participant_list)
{
  for(i in time_list) 
  {
    IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique <- filter(IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique, Timepoint==time_list[i] )
  }
    IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique$participant_per_gene[IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique$gene == c] <- length(unique(IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique$ID[IgH_CDR3_post_challenge_unique$gene == c]))
  }
```

I would like the loops to end up calculating the number of participants per gene for each timepoint.

My data looks something like this:

| gene | Timepoint | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C0 | SP1 |
| 2 | C1 | SP2 |
| 1 | C0 | SP4 |
| 3 | C0 | SP2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved without the use of a loop using `dplyr`. Loops tend to get slow and cumbersome when your data becomes large.

First, use `group_by` to group the data by the relevant column and then count the number of unique IDs within each group.

```
library(dplyr)
> dat %>% group_by(Timepoint, gene) %>% summarise(n = length(unique(ID)))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Timepoint     n
  <chr>     <int>
1 C0            3
2 C1            1
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the number of participants per gene at each timepoint. I tried using your solution but it calculated the number of participants per timepoint

Comment: My bad - let me rewrite it.